# jQuery UI Autocomplete get input element on source function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there any way to get input element on Autocomplete source function? `$(this)` not referring to input of autocomplete instance.

jsFiddle sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/442/).

```
<input type="text" data-code="foo" placeholder="type something ..." class="suggest" />
<input type="text" data-code="foo2" placeholder="type something ..." class="suggest" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(".suggest").autocomplete({
            delay: 100,
            source: function (request, response) {

                // get foo here,: $(this).data("code"); not working

                // Suggest URL
                var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY";
                suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

                // JSONP Request
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    url: suggestURL
                })
                .success(function(data){
                    response(data[1]);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You mean you wanna access the $("#suggest") within the Autocomplete source function?

Comment: Yes, but not with $("#suggest") selector. I need relative one

Comment: relative one? Sorry I don't quite get it. Can you elaborate a bit? if you need this itself to do something, you can save it tho.

Comment: @MichelleTan, I have just edit question. think that i have 2 input, and init autocomplete with class selector. i need input of autocomplete in source function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.element` gets the current element on source function.

```
$(".suggest").autocomplete({
            delay: 100,
            source: function (request, response) {

                this.element.data("code"); 

                // Suggest URL
                var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY";
                suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

                // JSONP Request
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    url: suggestURL
                })
                .success(function(data){
                    response(data[1]);
                });
            }
        });
```

Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/445/)